# Ternary relationship or 3 binary relationship?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

Why is a **3 binary relationship relationship representation** more general than **one ternary relationship representation**?

Comment: In general, 3 binary relationships aren't equivalent to a ternary relationship.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Think of it this way - is 3D space equivalent to three 2D planes? Can you construct a solid cube from 3 sheets of paper? Is front, side and top-down photos a more general representation of an object than a 3D model?

Answer (score 4):

Because with 3 binary relationships each involved entity is related **separately** with each one of the others two.

Assumed that ternary relationship in essential only when you have a many-to-many-to-many relationship (otherwise you can rewrite it adding a relational entity linked with binary relationships to the others three), let's take an example:

Suppose that you have the entities A, B and C, and three relationships that link the entities "like a triangle". Now, suppose that set of tuples a1 is related to the sets b1 and c1. Using 3 binary relationships, it's not requested that b1 and c1 are related. for example, b1 can be related to c2, that can partially overlap c1 or be completely disjoined.

With a ternary relationship, instead, b1 must be related to c1.

So you can see that with 3 binary relationships you can have much more combinations.

Answer (score 0):

In general one defines properties of relationships, like cardinality (only on object of a set can partecipate to the relationships or more than one, for istance), and totality/partiality (all the objects of the set *must* partecipate / *can* partecipate to the relationship).

So, limiting to these two properties with the two possibilities, in a ternary relation one has 12 possible combinations of values for the properties (3 x 2 for cardinality and 3 x 2 for totality).

If a ternary relationship is represented instead with 3 binary relationships, there are, for each endpoint of a relationship (there are six of them) 4 possibilities (single or multiple, tutal or partial), so in total one can have 24 possible combinations, that this a number of possible specifications which is the double with respect to that of the ternary relationship.